# Wrong computation with N

Tags: numerics

I was trying to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121594/24935) using Mathematica 8.04. I did this:

```
f[n_] := 2 Cos[2^(-1 + n) ArcCos[5/2]]
Table[{n, N[f[n+1]/Product[f[k], {k, 1, n}]]}, {n, 1, 20}]
```

and I got

```
{{1, 4.6 + 0. I}, {2, 4.58261 + 0. I}, {3, 4.58258 + 0. I}, {4, 
4.58258 + 0. I}, {5, 4.58258 + 0. I}, {6, 4.58258 + 0. I}, {7, 
4.58258 + 0. I}, {8, 4.58258 + 0. I}, {9, 0. + 0. I}, {10, 
0. + 0. I}, {11, 0. + 0. I}, {12, 0. + 0. I}, {13, 0. + 0. I}, {14, 
0. + 0. I}, {15, 0. + 0. I}, {16, 0. + 0. I}, {17, 0. + 0. I}, {18, 
0. + 0. I}, {19, 0. + 0. I}, {20, 0. + 0. I}}
```

There is something wrong after `n=9`:

```
N[f[10]/Product[f[k], {k, 1, 9}]]
0. + 0. I
N[f[10]]/N[Product[f[k], {k, 1, 9}]]
4.58258 + 0. I
```

What is the problem here? I think the first input should be more accurate than the last one.

Comment: I am not exactly clear about who these things work, but Mathematica can keep track of the precision of results and increase precision as necessary to obtain a good enough result.  I think this mechanism only works if you don't use machine numbers (don't use the FPU), but instead use Mathematica's arbitrary precision floating point numbers.  To do this, you need to specify the precision explicitly---it can be greater or less than machine precision but it needs to be given explicitly.  This is what Vitaliy suggests as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will fix the problem:

```
Partition[
  Table[{n, N[f[n + 1]/Product[f[k], {k, 1, n}], 10]}, {n, 1, 20}],
        2] // Grid
```

with output:

[image]

The fix I added is precision `10` specification to the function `N[... , 10]`. If you read **[Documentation for `N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html)** in section "More Information" you find:

"`N[expr]` gives a machine-precision number, so long as its magnitude is between `$MinMachineNumber` and `$MaxMachineNumber`."

Evaluating this:

```
In[1]:= $MaxMachineNumber
Out[1]= 1.79769*10^308
```

tells us that when your `Table` reaches `n=9` you hit the greater than `$MaxMachineNumber` case:

```
In[2]:= N[f[9 + 1]]
Out[2]= 2.463534156527763*10^348 + 0. I
```

note `348 > 308` exponent. So now you should explicitly specify the precision you want, like I did with `N[... , 10]` for example.

Also, to clarify the nature of repeating `4.5826...`, I played a bit with *Mathematica* to come up with a "conjecture":

$$\frac{2\cos\left(2^n \cos^{-1}\frac52\right)}{\prod_{k=1}^n 2\cos\left(2^{k-1} \cos^{-1}\frac52\right)}=\sqrt{21}\coth\left(2^n \cosh^{-1}\frac52\right)$$

So because `Coth` saturates quickly at 1 we have our limit for large arguments

```
In[3]:= N@Sqrt[21]
Out[3]= 4.58258
```

yet *the numbers in your* `Table` should of course decrease very slowly in "not printed" after-decimal-point part due to decreasing `Coth` function. And this is why the 1st number is 4.6:

```
In[4]:= TrigExpand[Sqrt[21] Coth[2 ArcCosh[5/2]]]
Out[4]= 23/5
```

Comment: How did you use Mathematica to come up with the conjecture?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this seems to be a bug,

```
f[n_] := 2 Cos[2^(-1 + n) ArcCos[5/2]]

a = f[10]/Product[f[k], {k, 1, 9}];

Accuracy[N[a]]
```

Gives an accuracy of about 300, which clearly is not true.
However, `Accuracy[N[a,2]]` gives a correct output.
Also, using `TrigExpand[a]//N` works.

Comment: The reason that `Accuracy[0.]` returns `307.653` has been explained before but I cannot find the post, and I cannot remember the explanation.